# iTunes music purchases after changing country

Tags: itunes, music, itunes-store

Are iTunes music purchases still available once I change the store country, assuming that both stores offer the same content which is associated with my account?

I am just concerned about making a substantial investment in music purchases now and not having the ability to download the files after crossing borders.

Answer (score 0):

Your account has an associated country based on your credit card address. As long as you keep your account you should have access to the content, but I think you'll need to make a new account once you get a credit card in the new country. I don't know if you can have 2 accounts active in iTunes at the same time but I'm pretty sure you can switch between accounts.